# How to set conditional exception breakpoints in CLION

Tags: debugging, clion

Is it possible to set a condition on a exception breakpoint in JetBrain's CLion (c++ equivalent of IntelliJ).

The debugging breakpoints allow to set conditions for Line Breakpoints and Symbolic Breakpoints. What I would like to have is a condition for Exception Breakpoints such as "break only if the exception is of type FooEx".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set breakpoint conditions in CLion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53374394/how-to-set-breakpoint-conditions-in-clion)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53374394/how-to-set-breakpoint-conditions-in-clion .