# How to set breakpoint conditions in CLion

Tags: c, debugging, clion

I am having some problems with a C application. I am writing in `CLion` (windows) and I have a `for` loop from `1 to 1000` but at some point around `i = 600` the code inside the loop returns something wrong.

At this point, I am not interested in why there is this problem but in how to find it so I tried to debug the application but it is impossible to hit `F7` 600 times.

So is there any way that I can start debugging when I get to let's say 590?

Comment: Did you try [reading the documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/configuring-breakpoints.html)?

Comment: @fredrik Yes I did but it is unclear to me the way the condition has to be syntaxed. I tried i=590 but it did not work.

Comment: Thank you for posting a question.  Please include a main() function and provide a [Compilable, Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  This helps us help you.  If you can make your problem as simple as possible while still creating the failure, it will help us isolate the issues that will make your code work correctly.  It is easier to respond to questions with code.

Comment: The conditional would have to be `i == 590`.  Because the `i=590` would make an assignment rather than a comparison and no break would happen.

Comment: @JohnMurray The actual code is too complicated (the code in separated in different files etc) so it is a bit difficult to simplify it. Although making `i == 590` worked so my problem is solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CLion allows you to set a conditional breakpoint.  Consider the code below which will exhibit bad behavior on loop 601 as it runs off the end of the array.

To catch this, set a breakpoint on the line where the assignment is being made.

Then, right click on the breakpoint and add the following to the conditional box in the dialog:

```
i == 599
```

Then, run the code, and the debugger will stop at the breakpoint only when i == 599.  It's magical!

```c++
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char array[600];

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        // code that does something

        array[i] = 0xff; // set breakpoint here!
        //, then right click and add conditional:  i == 590
    }

    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```